# Any languages where string default value = ""?

Tags: c#

Are there any programming languages where the default value of a string is "" ? If so, what are they?

Comment: BASIC maybe its been a while.

Comment: C++ when using the standard library's `string` type

Comment: I would say all languages using [Pascal-style string representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_%28computer_science%29#Length-prefixed).

Comment: @mouviciel That's not true. .Net uses length-prefixed strings, but the default value of `string` is `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One example is haskell. Although, strings don't really exist in haskell. The `String` type is just an alias for `[Char]`, that is, a list of characters.

`"test"` is exactly equivalent to (and indeed gets desugared to) `['t', 'e', 's', 't']` and `""` is exactly equivalent to `[]`

I believe there are plenty more languages where strings are just lists of characters where this is true, as well as any language with strings, but no null references.

Comment: That doesn't make a string's default value "". Try doing the following: `data Foo = Foo { bar :: String }`, `foo = Foo {}`, `bar foo`. You will get bottom (an error). Something like `myString :: String` isn't even syntactically valid.

Comment: The error given is `Fields of `Foo' not initialised: bar, In the expression: Foo {}, In an equation for `it': it = Foo {}`. To me this seems kind of analogous to the following C# code: `int n; int m = 1 + n;` which also throws, but `default(int)` is still 0. Default values and uninitialized values are different in my mind, but I might be mistaken when it comes to haskell.

Comment: I'd also note that it isn't `bar foo` that throws, it is the type constructor. you can't bind `Foo {}` to anything, even lazily (at least I can't after having tried for a while now). The error comes from constructing a value without initializing all fields. I think it might be a bit misleading to speak about default values at all in haskell though, so I agree the answer might not be very good.

Comment: You can bind `Foo {}` to things pretty easily, you just can't call `bar` on it. Code example: `a = Foo {}`, `b = a { bar = "bar"}`. Also while the error given is "field not initialized", the actual VALUE of `bar`, is \_|\_, or bottom. If someone asked me the default value for any type in Haskell with no further context, I would say \_|\_. Now you could say the Monoidal default, or Alternative default, and get a more meaningful answer. But there is no such `default` function in Haskell that works for all types. In fact the one function with the correct type `:: t`, is `undefined`, or \_|\_.